# Why aren’t my villagers breeding?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I’ve got one villager up 7 blocks surrounded with 6 doors. On ground level I have villagers who are supposed to breed. They are willing, their inventories are full of potatoes, and I’ve been sitting here for hours.  Hearts are popping up above their heads but nothing happens. I am playing on Xbox One.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your setup?

Comment: Sure! It’s up there now

Comment: I read this quickly, read 'bleeding' instead or 'breeding'. Tought I was clicking on a question about some satanic mod or something. :p

Comment: @TheMattbat999  it’s up there

Comment: @CarterRay Can I assume from you overriding my edit that you were actually playing on the [Xbox One Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Xbox_One_Edition) of Minecraft?

Comment: @pppery yes, when this was posted nearly a year ago, it was on the console edition of the game. Which I’ve since learned is not kind when dealing with villager mechanics..

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying; I've been doing a batch retag of questions from this often-misused tag, on the assumption that people aren't likely to be asking questions about games that were superseded several months before the question was posted. It appears my assumption was wrong in this case.

Comment: @pppery you’re all good, I’ve always preferred the console editions to bedrock, and I deleted bedrock within an hour of downloading it. Now I’m full on java edition anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Villagers breeding is directly related to the number of doors in their village (Naturally generated or otherwise) The Villagers will only breed when the number of villagers is below 35% of the number of doors in the village, Supposing you have 6 doors then the villages population cap is 2.1 villagers. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you need more doors

Comment: There are far enough below that they shouldn’t be counted in the population census but still breed to. They had hearts, thanks for your comment, I have scratched the whole thing and thrown a lot of doors down now though