# Villager breeding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So when i go to breed villagers i usually give each one 3 bread. But in this new world i have made to play with a friend they don't want to make babies. When the bread is given to them they have hearts around them but then after a couple of seconds another particle comes up... The particle when you hit them. The gray cloud with lightning i guess that's what it is... Anyone know how to fix that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren’t my villagers breeding?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/325091/why-aren-t-my-villagers-breeding)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding doors to the village.(if you don’t want doors to ruin the view then put the doors one block under the village)

Answer (score -1):

They removed it in new worlds :(

Comment: No, this is simply false.

Answer (score -1):

They need beds for the babys to sleep and have access to

Comment: Or to word it differently: Villagers only breed if their village capacity isn't reached yet, which is determined by the number of beds that they can pathfind to.

Comment: I did place beds... I'll try placing more beds. Maybe i have too many lol

Comment: I placed more beds still the same result.